# TypeORM: How to link exist categories with new posts

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, relational-database, typeorm

I'm building a blog rest API based on Wordpress database schema!

I have linked `wp_posts` table with `wp_term_taxonomy` table with many to many relationships using typeORM framework

## The problem is now when I'm creating a post with categories using cascade feature

## it generates new categories even if it exists already I can't use exist categories with new posts!

## So I need to just relation the existing categories ( taxonomies ) with new posts.

**the code:**

```
private createPost = async (request: express.Request, response: express.Response) => {

    const data: WpPostsModel = request.body;
    const entries: any[] = request.body.taxonomies;
    let taxonomies = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
        const entry = entries[i];

        let newTaxonomy = new WpTermTaxonomyModel();

        newTaxonomy = {
            taxonomy: entry.taxonomy,
            description: '',
            term: {
                name: entry.term.name,
                slug: entry.term.name.replace(/\s+/g, '-'),
                term_group: 0,
                // term_id: entry.term.term_id
            }
        }

        taxonomies.push(newTaxonomy);
    }


    const newPost = await this.postRepository.create({
        post_title: data.post_title,
        post_content: data.post_content,
        post_excerpt: data.post_excerpt,
        post_type: 'post',
        post_mime_type: '',
        comment_status: 'closed',
        ping_status: 'closed',
        to_ping: '',
        pinged: '',
        comment_count: 0,
        post_parent: 0,
        post_status: 'publish',
        post_content_filtered: '',
        post_password: '',
        post_name: ( data.post_title ) ? data.post_title.replace(/\s+/g, '-') : '',
        post_date: new Date(),
        post_date_gmt: new Date(),
        post_modified: new Date(),
        post_modified_gmt: new Date(),
        taxonomies
    });

    await this.postRepository.save(newPost);

    response.send(newPost);

}
```

wp_posts entity

```
@Entity({ name: 'wp_posts', synchronize: false })
export class WpPostsModel {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    public ID?: number;

    @Column()
    public post_date?: string;

    @Column()
    public post_date_gmt?: string;

    @Column()
    public post_content?: string;

    @Column()
    public post_title?: string;

    ...etc

    @ManyToMany(() => WpTermTaxonomyModel)
    @JoinTable({
        name: 'wp_term_relationships',
        joinColumn: {
            name: 'object_id',
            referencedColumnName: 'ID'
        },
        inverseJoinColumn: {
            name: 'term_taxonomy_id',
            referencedColumnName: 'termTaxonomyId'
        }
    })
    public categories?: WpTermTaxonomyModel[];

}
```

wp_term_taxonomy entity

```
@Entity({ name: 'wp_term_taxonomy', synchronize: false })
export class WpTermTaxonomyModel {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({ name: 'term_taxonomy_id' })
    public termTaxonomyId?: number;

    @OneToOne(() => WpTermsModel)
    @JoinColumn({ name: 'term_id' })
    public term?: WpTermsModel;

    @Column()
    public taxonomy?: string;

    @Column()
    public description?: string;

    @Column()
    public parent?: number;

}
```

wp_terms entity

```
@Entity({ name: 'wp_terms', synchronize: false })
export class WpTermsModel {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    public term_id?: number;

    @Column()
    public name?: string;

    @Column()
    public slug?: string;

    @Column()
    public term_group?: number;
}
```

Comment: Share your entity classes for WpPostsModel and WpTermTaxonomyModel

Comment: thanks for reply I have edited the question with the entities

Comment: I don't know if this is a bit late to reply you, but have you tried to use { unique: true }?inside the decorator to restrict to upload unique values?